# Как составить такое регулярное выражение?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Прошу помощи в составлении регулярного выражения, моё почему-то не работает.

```
src:(url\((.*)\),?[\s]?)+
```

Строка

```
src:url(sd), url(sdasdads), url(asd;sdrr);font-style: normal;
```

На выходе должен быть список url(...)

Comment: `asd;sdrr` - это обязательное условие?

Comment: @ЮрийКот, в следующий раз указываете язык программирования, на котором вы хотите получить решение.

Comment: Там такой пример 
@font-face{font-family:dashicons;src:url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgA...ddfd), url(../fonts/dashicons.ttf) format("truetype"),url(../fonts/dashicons.svg#dashicons) format("svg");font-weight:400;font-style:normal}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let str = `src:url(sd), url(sdasdads), url(asd;sdrr);font-style: normal;`;
console.log(str.match(/(?<=src:|\,\s)url\([^)]+\)/g));
```

Comment: Находит не только `src`, попробуйте строку
`src:url(sd), url(sdasdads), url(asd;sdrr);font-style: normal;background-image:url(link)`

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach, добавлено.

Comment: Что добавлено? Толку от этой добавки? Все равно будет, что угодно выбирать по `url`.

Comment: @And, у вас какие-то проблемы с моим выражением? К тому же автор не давал информацию на 100%, что именно из атрибута `src` захват должен производиться.

Comment: Проблемы у вас с чтением, автор привел пример разбора, а у вас, что `src`, что `background` - получается одно и тоже.

Comment: Ммм.. для меня работает это решение, выбирает только для `src`

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach, действительно проблема есть, это только для 1 вхождения `url` работает стабильно, если у другого атрибута будет 2 и более `url`, то он сделает захват.

Comment: @Let'ssayPie зобанили беднягу :-D